# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str - While accessing element of list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python. Here I'm trying to access `list` object in python which is throwing following error.

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

---

`print(a)`

**Output:**

```
['{"id":9,"name":"Foo"}']
```

`print(type(a))`

**Output:**

```
<class 'list'>
```

`print(a['id'])`

**Output:**

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

`print(a[0]['id'])`

**Output:**

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

`print(a[0])`

**Output:**

```
{"id":9,"name":"Foo"}
```

---

#### Expected Output

```
9
```

Comment: Expected output?

Comment: `a` should be `[{"id":9,"name":"Foo"}]` if you want to access it as a dictionary. For accessing the id `a[0]['id']` would be the right approach.Since you should first access the list element then choose the desired key value pair from dictionary.

Comment: @MiladEsrafiliyan I tried but it giving me `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: As I said the dictionary in the list **should not** be covered with '. Because python would mistake it as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was solve this by the following

1. Passing `[{"id":9,"name":"Foo"}]` instead of `['{"id":9,"name":"Foo"}']` which can done by removing `json_encode()` while sending data to Flask Application. In my case was from **Laravel / PHP**.
2. By accessing element using `a[0]['id']` as pointed by [@mhhabib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5929910/mhhabib)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you have taken the dictionary mistakenly with ' ' which indicates `'{"id": 9, "name": "Foo"}'` as a string. Remove quotation marks and iterate the list. Assume the list size is fixed to one dictionary list.

```
a = [{"id":9, "name":"Foo"}]

id = a[0]['id']
print(id)
```

Let's your list be long like

```
a = [{"id": 9, "name": "Foo"}, {"id": 10, "name": "Bar"},{"id": 11, "name": "FooBar"}]
```

Then get id by using loop

```
for l in a:
    print(l['id'])
```

Comment: I tried but it giving me `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: Copy the above code and run it in your IDE. You're getting the error because you have taken a list of dictionary but expect `a['id'] ` but in the list there is no element of `id`

Comment: @Maqsud remove ' ' from the dictionary `['{"id":9, "name":"Foo"}']` to `[{"id":9, "name":"Foo"}]`

Comment: @mhahabib, I'm returning `['{"id":9, "name":"Foo"}']` while `print(a)`

Comment: `'{"id":9, "name":"Foo"}'` this a string and there is no scope to get id. For sure check `print(type(a[0]))` is `str`

Comment: `print(type(a[0]))` is `<class 'str'>`

Comment: @Maqsud please go through the whole answer and comment. You can't get any output from a string by indexing any char/string value. If you need only `9` from a string then use `a[0][7]`. The index always must be an integer. As i said to get `id` from the list of dictionary you must be removed inverted comma from both end

Answer (score 2):

you are storing the dictionary as a string so the error you are getting is expected.
If you want to access the id in the dictionary then store it as the dictionary itself.
To access the id value you can check the below code

```
a=[{"id":9,"name":"Foo"}]
b=a[0]['id']
print(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

list have not attribute allows key and value.
then you can try with dictonary.